# Maximum message count - Facebook PHP api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a facebook app and since its my first facebook app, I am facing some problems with the PHP API.

I want to fetch the name and profile ID of the sender who sent maximum no. of messages. I am new to PHP and facing problems in proceeding after getting inbox object. Any help would be appreciated.

I am stuck here

```
$inbox = $user_profile['inbox'];
```

`user_profile` is an array where the data of user's profile and account is stored.

Comment: whats the error/s you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting any errors, instead i am confused with facebook api user guid. In that, the discription for message_count object is given that it will return an integer with no. messages in THIS thread whereas i collected objects of a inbox, not a particular thread and neither i have entered a particular thread. So i need help in getting the name of sender who sent max. no messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PHP API to make a FQL request to the thread table.  This will give you the Facebook ID of the originator :

```
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT originator, message_count FROM thread WHERE  viewer_id = 8675309 and folder_id = 0 ORDER BY message_count DESC LIMIT 0,10");

$threads = $facebook->api($params);
```

Set the viewer_id appropriately. Notice the ORDER BY and LIMIT.  This FQL is giving you the TOP 10 senders based on message_count. Then, if you need to get their name :

```
foreach($threads as $thread)
{
   print_r($thread);
   $originator = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/$thread['originator']");
   $originator_object = json_decode($originator);
   print $originator_object->name;
}
```